# reportlab, Long word or URI doesn't wrap inside table cell

Tags: python, reportlab

Creating a table with cells that contain long words doesn’t seem to work as expected, i.e. the words are not wrapped automatically inside the paragraphs and the table cell breaks page layout by being too wide.
Additionally the rendered text of the URI contains strange characters ( `;` ) that are not in the original text used to create the paragraph.

How can long word wrapping be controlled for a paragraph inside a table cell ?

Here is a minimal code ( using macOS Sonoma, arm64, python==3.10, reportlab==3.6.11 ):

```py
import re
from pathlib import Path

from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import portrait, A4
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, TableStyle, Table, Image

PAGE_SIZE = portrait(A4)
PAGE_MARGIN_TOP = 2 * cm
PAGE_MARGIN_LEFT = 0.7 * cm
PAGE_MARGIN_RIGHT = 0.7 * cm
PAGE_MARGIN_BOTTOM = 1 * cm
PAGE_CONTENT_WIDTH = PAGE_SIZE[0] - PAGE_MARGIN_LEFT - PAGE_MARGIN_RIGHT
PAGE_CONTENT_HEIGHT = PAGE_SIZE[1] - PAGE_MARGIN_TOP - PAGE_MARGIN_BOTTOM

LEADING_FACTOR = 1.25

BODY_TEXT_STYLE_NAME = "BodyText"
BODY_TEXT_FONT_NAME = "Roboto" # you can use "Courier" too, same problem
BODY_TEXT_FONT_SIZE = 12

STYLES = getSampleStyleSheet()
BODY_TEXT_STYLE = STYLES[BODY_TEXT_STYLE_NAME]
BODY_TEXT_STYLE.fontName = BODY_TEXT_FONT_NAME
BODY_TEXT_STYLE.fontSize = BODY_TEXT_FONT_SIZE
BODY_TEXT_STYLE.leading = BODY_TEXT_FONT_SIZE * LEADING_FACTOR
BODY_TEXT_STYLE.wordWrap = True # this has no effect whatsoever, commenting it out does not improve anything
BODY_TEXT_STYLE.splitLongWords = True # this has no effect whatsoever, commenting it out does not improve anything
BODY_TEXT_STYLE.uriWasteReduce = 0.0001 # using a greater value make things sometimes even worse


def create_pdf():
   output_path = Path.home() / "tmp" / "test.pdf"
   doc = DocTemplate(
       output_path.as_posix(),
       pagesize=PAGE_SIZE,
       topMargin=PAGE_MARGIN_TOP,
       leftMargin=PAGE_MARGIN_LEFT,
       rightMargin=PAGE_MARGIN_RIGHT,
       bottomMargin=PAGE_MARGIN_BOTTOM,
       showBoundary=True,
   )
   paragraphs = [
       Paragraph("Test Text", style=BODY_TEXT_STYLE),
       Paragraph(
           "Test Text averyveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryvveryveryverylongword",
           style=BODY_TEXT_STYLE),
       Paragraph(

           "Label: This is text with a long URI https://www.example.com/hello/world/this/is/a/very/long/website/path/11111/222222/?abc=123&def=756&ghj=888",
           style=BODY_TEXT_STYLE),
   ]
   cells = [
       [
           paragraphs,
           [Image(create_placeholder_image(200, 200), width=3.5 * cm, height=3.5 * cm)],
       ]
   ]
   table = Table(
       cells,
       colWidths=[
           "*",
           4 * cm,
       ],
   )
   table.setStyle(
       TableStyle(
           [
               # align image and qr
               ("ALIGN", (0, 0), (-1, -1), "CENTER"),
               ("VALIGN", (0, 0), (-2, -1), "CENTER"),
               ("VALIGN", (-1, 0), (-1, -1), "TOP"),
               # force padding
               ("TOPPADDING", (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
               ("BOTTOMPADDING", (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
               ("LEFTPADDING", (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
               ("RIGHTPADDING", (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
               # table borders, for debugging
               ("INNERGRID", (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.red),
               ("BOX", (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.red),
           ]
       )
   )
   flowables = [table]
   doc.build(flowables)
   print(f"Saved {output_path}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   create_pdf()
```

[image: pdf screenshot]

Comment: I debugged the reportlab code and it seems that it actually splits the long words into fragments and multiple lines ( e.g. Paragraph.blPara property after Paragraph.wrap() was called ) but the paragraph is not rendered with those fragments. Maybe table code replaces the paragraph on-the-fly breaking things ?

Comment: I tried to insert invisible spaces into the log word ( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space ) but that doesn't break the long word either.

Comment: The only workaround so far is inserting a zero-sized-space using html styling inside the paragraph text at a position in the long word: "....<font size=0> </font>....". That basically allows reportlab to break the long word. BUT selecting/copying that word with a pdf viewer still reveals that space character inside the long word.

Comment: reportlab mailing-list confirmed that this is a bug - I will update the question/answer when a fix is released.